# Extract a column from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Just a basic question but which block me a lot.
How can we extract a column from a DataFrame and have a DataFrame as output ?

Suppose that we have :

```
>>> dfM
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 17544 entries, 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2016-12-31 23:00:00
Data columns (total 23 columns):
T1       17544  non-null values
T2       17544  non-null values

>>> df = dfM['T1']
```

Here df is not a DataFrame. I found a subterfuge by copy the DataFrame and del all columns but it's very time consumming.

Alexis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[[]]` instead of `[]`:

```
df = dfM[['T1']]
```

For example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(dict(a=range(10), b=range(10)))

type(df['b'])
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
type(df[['b']])
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

This works because it is passing a list of 1 (`['b']`) to the column subset operator.

Comment: Very well ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a DataFrame with the column you want and the original index:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(dfM.T1, index = dfM.index)
```